# Correction the code

Tags: php, html

I need your help

I have worked code display and demo, which is currently not running

I will put the code, and I hope you understand the significance of it

This code

```
<form method="POST" action=<?php ($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>>
    <p>chose url: <select size="1" name="D1">
    <option url="https://drive.google.com/file/d/$google/view" value="google_drive">google drive</option>
    <option url="https://www.cloudy.ec/embed.php?id=$cloudy" value="clody">clody</option>
    </select>    <input type="text" name="T1" size="40" value="insert code">    <input type="submit" value="go" name="B1"><input type="reset" value="reset" name="B2"></p>
</form>
```

[image: demo]

thank you all

Comment: what is the issue and what you want to achieve?

Comment: i´ve already seen this question yesterday with the same picture and it didn´t have a description what you want to do. Today there is no difference.

Comment: @Luminous_Dev Forgive me, because I could not deliver the information to you because of the weakness of my ability to converse in English as required

When I chose (Google)
I put all such code as well as 123456789
This immediately shows the full link and this particular form
GoogleDrive ^ https: //drive.google.com/file/d/123456789/preview

If you can not understand I'll try to explain again that I find a solution to my problem

Comment: @KevinEsche Yes already apologized twice to deliver the information to you
I have replied to what I want

Comment: `<form method="POST" action=<?php ($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>>` Needs quotes around the action - `action='<?php ($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>'`

Comment: Please come up with a more descriptive title.

Comment: One problem here is that variables are not being echo'd.  e.g. probably should read: `https://drive.google.com/file/d/<?= $google ?>/view` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this?

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['D1']) && !empty($_POST['T1'])){
    $providers = array(
        'google_drive' => 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/{replace}/view',
        'clody' => 'https://www.cloudy.ec/embed.php?id={replace}'
    );

    if(isset($providers[$_POST['D1']])){

        $url =  str_replace('{replace}', $_POST['T1'], $providers[$_POST['D1']]);
        echo "Your url is $url";
    }


}
?>

<form method="POST" action=<?php ($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>>
    <p>chose url: 
    <select size="1" name="D1">
        <option value="google_drive">google drive</option>
        <option value="clody">clody</option>
    </select>    
    <input type="text" name="T1" size="40" value="insert code">    
    <input type="submit" value="go" name="B1"><input type="reset" value="reset" name="B2">
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for trying to understand me
I'm going to test the code

Comment: Yes yes this is required
thank you for helping me
But the last thing I need to develop and ease of use

You need to be displayed without updating the page

Comment: You need to use javascript and ajax. I'm not going to write it all for you, you need to work that out on your own. If you get stuck with the javascript ask another stackoverflow question.

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept the answer.

Comment: OK
Sify this present time
Thank you from the bottom of my heart to help

Answer (score 0):

you should do like this.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['B1'])){
     $arrUrl = array(
      'google_drive' => 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/'.$_POST['T1'].'/view',
      'clody' => 'https://www.cloudy.ec/embed.php?id='.$_POST['T1']
    );

   $url = $arrUrl[$_POST['D1']];
   //echo  $url = $arrUrl[$_POST['D1']];
   //exit();
   header('location:'.$url); 


}
?>
<form method="POST" action=<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?> >
    <p>chose url: <select size="1" name="D1">
    <option value="google_drive">google drive</option>
    <option value="clody">clody</option>
    </select>
     <input type="text" name="T1" size="40" placeholder="insert code">  
       <input type="submit" value="go" name="B1">
       <input type="reset" value="reset" name="B2"></p>
</form>
```

remove url="http:link" from option..

please find the attached image.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFR4k.png)

Thankyou.

Comment: Thank you mr syed